# Vending Machin in python - categories and total price

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm Python Beginner.
I want to make a vending machine. I'd like to choose a category first, and then choose a drink or food. I checked other codes here to get the answer I want but they are a little different than mine. In my program, I take the user step by step. After that, I want to show the total price. Then I want to ask you how to pay. What should I do?
Here is my code

```
main_menu = ["Coffees", "Espresso", "Latte", "Tea and Milk", "Food"]
Coffees_dict = {'Coffee': 2.10, 'Iced Coffee’: 2.65, ‘Cold Brew (seasonal)’:3.95, ‘Cafe Au Lait’:2.45}
Espresso_dict = {'Americano':1.95, 'Iced Americano’:2.45, ‘Mochatella’:4.25, ‘Iced Mochatella’:4.75, ‘Cafe Caramel/Mocha’:4.70, ‘Iced Cafe Mocha/Caramel’:4.20}
Latte_dict = {'Chai Latte':3.45, 'Iced Chai Latte':3.75}
Tea and milk_dict = {'Hot Tea’:1.95, ‘Hot Chocolate’:1.75, ‘Milk’:1.50, ‘Chocolate Milk’:1.95, ‘Soda’:2.25}
Food_dict = {'Donut’:1.25, ‘Filled Donut’:1.50, ‘Apple Fritter’:2.95, ‘Cinnamon roll’:2.95, ‘Muffin’:2.95, ‘Scone’:2.95}
total = 0

def main_menu_func():
    print(main_menu)
    x = str(input("Choose the category you want. Type NONE to finish."))
    if( x == 'Coffees'):
        print(Coffees_func())
    elif ( x == 'Espresso'):
        print(Espresso_func())
    elif (x == 'Latte'):
        print(Latte_func())
    elif ( x == 'Tea and milk'):
        print(Tea and milk_func())
    elif ( x == 'Food'):
        print(Food_func())
    else:
        print("Please pick up your items and don't forget your change.")
        print(change_func())


def Coffees_func():
    print(Coffees_dict)
    print("Type in the coffees you want. If you do not want a drink type NONE:")
    drink = str(input())
    if (drink == 'Coffee'):
        water_cost = 2.10
        ## update the total cost?
        print(another_drink())
    elif (drink == 'Iced Coffee'):
        drink_cost = 2.65
        ## update the total cost?
        print(another_drink())
    elif (drink == 'Cold Brew (seasonal)'):
        drink_cost = 3.95
        ## update the total cost?
    elif (drink == 'Cafe Au Lait'):
        drink_cost = 2.45        ## update the total cost?
        print(another_drink())
    elif (drink == 'NONE'):
        print(main_menu_func())
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid response")
        print(drinks_func())




SAME FOR THE OTHERS






def change_func():
        print("Thank you for buying from us.")
        ## update the total cost
        change = coins - total
        print("You paid", coins, "and you bought with", str(total), ". Your change is: ", (change))



print('Welcome to the vending machine. The maximum number of coins you can enter is 3.')
coins = (float(input('Please enter your coins: ')))

coin_type = (str(input('Are your coins AEDs? Please type YES or NO: ')))
if (coin_type == "YES"):
    print("You entered", str(coins), "Dirhams. Please select the category you want.")
    print(main_menu)
    print("Please type in the category you want:")
    category_selection = str(input())
    if(category_selection == 'Drinks'):
        print(drinks_func())
    elif(category_selection == 'Chips'):
        print(chips_func())
    else:
        print("Invalid response.")


#total = (drink_cost + chips_cost + candy_cost)

else:
    print('We only accept AED.')
```

Comment: What are ```chips_func()``` or ```drinks_func()```? Are they functions?

Comment: are you familiar with tkinter? You can use gui.

Comment: Why is this tagged pandas and group-by?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you want, but I found one bug in your code: when you wrote `print(Coffees_func())` you actually should have just ran `Coffees_func()` because the function prints and doesn't return. Also, the quotes in the dictionary at the top are strange but maybe that is just Stack Overflow